# Bitnami SSL setup on AWS Lightsail - I enter 'blog.domain.io' and it returns 'The following domains were not included: 'www.blog.domain.io'

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, subdomain, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

That's basically it. I enter the Bitnami HTTPS Configuration tool and enter the domains I want to configure, and I get this:

```
Please provide a valid space-separated list of domains for which you wish to 
configure your web server.

Domain list []: domain.io www.domain.io blog.domain.io

The following domains were not included: www.blog.domain.io. Do you want to add 
them? [Y/n]:
```

This is for a client and I'm on the clock, so I don't want to test entering `Y` or `n` and have an even bigger mess on my hands. AWS documentation and every material I can find on the topic makes no mention of this kind of result, and acts like all you have to do is enter the subdomains and everything's golden (e.g. [this article](https://www.webagentnavigator.com/webagent-blog/adding-ssl-security-to-the-sub-domains-on-the-aws-bitnami-server)).

The DNS for all three domains is already successfully setup at the registrar.

What am I missing?